# How to setup Jest for Unit testing normal with php project?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to setup the front end unit test for my PHP project.
I decided to go with Jest.

So this is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "staging-deploy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Staging deploy",
  "main": "GulpFile.js",
  "author": "some one",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.8.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-chmod": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-closure-compiler": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-duration": "0.0.0",
    "gulp-jasmine": "^2.4.2",
    "gulp-less": "^3.3.2",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-pixrem": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.3.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.11.0",
    "gulp-update": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-update-modul": "^1.5.5",
    "gulp-watch-less": "^1.0.1",
    "run-sequence": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^20.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

Then I made `__tests__` folder and making my first testing function like this.

// homepage.test.js

```
require('../modules/homepage.js');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', function() {
    expect(Homepage.sum.sumNumber(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

And this is my homepage.js

// homepage.js

```
var Homepage = {};

(function() {
    "use strict";

    Homepage.sum = {
        sumNumber: function(num1, num2) {
            return num1 + num2
        }
    };
})();
```

Then I ran `npm run test`
This is what I got:

```
FAIL  __tests__/homepage.test.js
  ● adds 1 + 2 to equal 3

    ReferenceError: Homepage is not defined

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/homepage.test.js:4:12)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

  ✕ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (2ms)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.138s, estimated 11s
```

Seems like my test file can not access the function inside my Homepage.js file.

How can I fix this and make it works?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Common js module loader does not work this way. If you want to export anything of a module you should attach it to module.exports object or simply overwrite it. this object is the only thing which will export from a module. so:

// homepage.js

```
"use strict";
var Homepage = {};

Homepage.sum = {
        sumNumber: function(num1, num2) {
            return num1 + num2
        }
    };

module.exports = Homepage;
```

**Note** that you don't need use an IIFE as all js files behave modular and have their own scope.

And then in your homepage.test.js file:

// homepage.test.js

```
var Homepage = require('../modules/homepage.js');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', function() {
    expect(Homepage.sum.sumNumber(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using Common js because the whole app is running without any `module.exports` so don' thin adding it is a good idea.

Comment: @varis.dara, you could prepare the common js modular written code for browsers using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or alternatively using an AMD module loading system like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) or use ES6 module pattern which is fairly new and only supported in latest browsers so you should use a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert it back to common js and then browserify it. All of these could easily be configured in a gulp task to be done automatically.